# Error: Cannot Start Container: stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory"

Tags: docker, busybox

I have been trying to create my own busybox base image.

```
# ./mkimage.sh -t pensu/busybox busybox-static
+ mkdir -p /var/tmp/docker-mkimage.US3tHy0uBQ/rootfs
+ tar --numeric-owner -caf /var/tmp/docker-mkimage.US3tHy0uBQ/rootfs.tar.xz -C /var/tmp/docker-mkimage.US3tHy0uBQ/rootfs '--transform=s,^./,,' .
+ cat > '/var/tmp/docker-mkimage.US3tHy0uBQ/Dockerfile'
+ rm -rf /var/tmp/docker-mkimage.US3tHy0uBQ/rootfs
+ docker build -t pensu/busybox /var/tmp/docker-mkimage.US3tHy0uBQ
Sending build context to Docker daemon 863.2 kB
Sending build context to Docker daemon 
Step 0 : FROM scratch
 ---> 
Step 1 : ADD rootfs.tar.xz /
 ---> 8eac78bfc9d6
Removing intermediate container ad9bbb8f7536
Successfully built 8eac78bfc9d6
+ rm -rf /var/tmp/docker-mkimage.US3tHy0uBQ
```

I can see the image is available with my docker repo.

```
# docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
pensu/busybox       latest              8eac78bfc9d6        7 seconds ago       2.476 MB
```

But when I try to do docker run, I always get the error:

```
# docker run -it pensu/busybox /bin/sh
exec: "/bin/sh": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directorytime="2015-04-09T16:03:45+05:30" level="fatal" msg="Error response from daemon: Cannot start container 8fe73b7832193c847d7975175a4be86d1f0b550b6a00b812bd4cdd18fe752468: exec: \"/bin/sh\": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory"
```

I am not able to understand why is it giving that error? Am I doing something wrong? How else can I validate that I am creating a correct image that is in working condition?

Comment: in my case, it was: the wrong endlines into shell file. Replacing to Unix style was help me

Comment: In my case, I had failed to specify a `WORKDIR`, and I had a `COPY . .` which was using my local `./bin` to overwrite `/bin` in the container.

Answer (score 89):

After you create image, check it with:

```
$ docker inspect $image_name
```

and check what you have in CMD option. For busy box it should be:

```
"Cmd": [
     "/bin/sh"
]
```

Maybe you are overwritting CMD option in your ./mkimage.sh

Comment: "Cmd": [
            "/bin/sh",
            "-c",
            "#(nop) ADD file:905ed83e56295de9b6eb24708b583e78e4e9a06d3a80184276b55b5db04d70aa in /"
        ], It is /bin/sh only.

Comment: If You want to run container You must provide task which will be performed by container, rigth now docker is executing /bin/sh. For example if you want to run jar inside your container try java -jar yourjar.jar

Comment: That's what I am thinking about. Is it not possible to get an interactive shell with an busybox image? What else could I run inside a busybox container?

Comment: You should be able to run busybox with simple command, as: docker run -d busybox /bin/sh -c "while true; do echo hello world; sleep 1; done". This will run your image in background and will echo hello world each 1 second.

Comment: Okay, it did create a container, I mean I got a container id, and then it gave me the same error. # docker run -d pensu/busybox /bin/sh -c "while true; do echo hello world; sleep 1; done"
d8db2c9c59e9cf36e577342c6ff746b23b7124eb28b94bc3aad4665a9f3d39a5
time="2015-04-10T12:26:02+05:30" level="fatal" msg="Error response from daemon: Cannot start container d8db2c9c59e9cf36e577342c6ff746b23b7124eb28b94bc3aad4665a9f3d39a5: exec: \"/bin/sh\": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory"

Comment: Because your image expects a main class to load your application inside a container, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25364940/how-to-create-docker-image-for-local-application-taking-file-and-value-parameter

Comment: @wsl, that link is about running Java in docker.  This question has nothing to do with Java.

Comment: The comment above says `"Cmd": [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "#(nop) ADD file:905ed83e56295de9b6eb24708b583e78e4e9a06d3a80184276b55b5db04d70aa in /" ]` - notice the `ADD` stuff; you have a typo in your `Dockerfile`.

Answer (score 45):

Using `$ docker inspect [imageID]` Incase the Image has no `/bin/bash` in the output, you can use command below: it worked for me perfectly

```
$ docker exec -it <container id> sh
```

Comment: OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: unable to start container process: exec: "sh": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown

Answer (score 44):

I hit this error ("stat /bin/bash: no such file or directory") when running the command:

```
docker exec -it 80372bc2c41e /bin/bash
```

The solution was to identify the kind of terminal (or shell) that is available on the container. To do so, I ran:

```
docker inspect 80372bc2c41e
```

In the output from that command, I saw:

```
"Cmd": [
    "/bin/sh",
    "-c",
    "gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:7082 server.app:app"
],
```

This tells me that there's a `/bin/sh` command available, and I was able to connect with:

```
docker exec -it 80372bc2c41e /bin/sh
```

Comment: What if there is null in CMD part?

Comment: Hmm that should mean there's no command being run in your container. Do you have a link to the Dockerfile?

Answer (score 18):

This error

> docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed:
>   container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec:
>   \"/bin/sh\": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory": unknown.

occurs when creating a docker image from base image eg. `scratch`. This is because the resulting image does not have a shell to execute the image. If your use:

```
ENV EXECUTABLE hello
cmd [$EXECUTABLE]
```

in your docker file, docker uses /bin/sh to parse the input string. and hence the error. Inspecting on the image, your will find:

```
$docker inspect <image-name>
"Entrypoint": [
                "/bin/sh",
                "-c",
                "[$HM_APP]"
            ]
```

This means that the ENTRYPOINT or CMD arguments will be parsed using /bin/sh -c. The solution that worked for me is to parse the command as a JSON array of string e.g.

```
cmd ["hello"]
```

and inspecting the image again:

```
"Entrypoint": [
                "hello"
            ]
```

This removes the dependence on /bin/sh the docker app can now execute the binary file. Example:

```
FROM scratch

# Environmental variables

# Copy files
ADD . /
# Home dir
WORKDIR /bin

EXPOSE 8083
ENTRYPOINT ["hospitalms"]
```

Hope this helps someone in future.

Comment: `As of Docker 1.5.0 (specifically, docker/docker#8827), FROM scratch is a no-op in the Dockerfile.  Using the scratch “image” signals to the build process that you want the next command in the Dockerfile to be the first filesystem layer in your image.`  This means that your container does not contain /bin/sh, or anything else (other than the linux kernel i assume)

Comment: Yes, you don't have a kernel attached to the image. Running any Linux command or docker shell dependent command will fail.

Comment: adding 
`WORKDIR /bin`
in my Dokerfile solve for me

Answer (score 7):

On Windows (msys) using Docker Toolbox/Machine, I had to add an extra `/` before `/bin/bash` to indicate that it was a *nix filepath.

So,
`docker run --rm -it <image>:latest //bin/bash`

Comment: What a great little trick. I did not know about this.

Comment: Awesome you saved me! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

check your image `cmd` using the command `docker inspect image_name` . The output might be like this:

```
"Cmd": [
    "/bin/bash",
    "-c",
    "#(nop) ",
    "CMD [\"/bin/bash\"]"
],
```

So use the command `docker exec -it container_id /bin/bash`. If your `cmd` output is different like this:

```
"Cmd": [
    "/bin/sh",
    "-c",
    "#(nop) ",
    "CMD [\"/bin/sh\"]"
],
```

Use `/bin/sh` instead of `/bin/bash` in the command above.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "exec: \"sh\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
```

In my case, I know the image works in other places, then was a corrupted local image.
I solved the issue removing the image (`docker rmi <imagename>`) and pulling it again(`docker pull <imagename>`).

I did a `docker system prune` too, but I think it's not mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly mention the ubuntu version in the docker file which you are trying to RUN,

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
```

Dont use like `FROM ubuntu:Latest`. This resolved my above "Cannot Start Container: stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory" issue