# Can't run Curl command inside my Docker Container

Tags: docker, shell, installation

I created a docker container from my OS X VM Docker host.  I created it using the run command and created the container based off the `ubuntu:xenial` image off docker hub.

I'm now connected to my container after it's created and logged in as root and at the command prompt inside my container.

I tried to install homebrew and for some reason, I can't run the command to install Homebrew:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

when I run that I get a bash:

> curl: command not found

Not sure why I'm not able to use curl here inside my container.

Comment: Why not just install curl from zip ? Is curl anywhere on your disk ?

Comment: based on Ubuntu image you can use apt-get install curl -y. RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get install curl -y CMD /bin/bash

Answer (score 320, accepted):

> curl: command not found

is a big hint, you have to install it with :

```
apt-get -y update; apt-get -y install curl
```

Comment: Hi, why would I want to use sudo? The container does not know sudo anyway..Nirojan's answer works

Comment: I think you have to remove the sudo for this to work in docker

Comment: u've assumed that it will be a debian image.  right answer in this case , but what about smaller unix images, any help ?

Comment: I dunno what you mean by smaller image. If it's debian based, it should just works

Comment: Needed this one.

Comment: /bin/sh: apt-get: not found
What now?

Comment: @mahboudz it means that the image you are using has another package manager. Which image are you using? Other common ones are yum and dnf, i.e. you may want to try `yum install curl` or `dnf install curl`

Comment: I have this in my docker file, I can see curl being installed when I build my docker file, yet I still get "curl: command not found"

Comment: In my case, the solution was slightly different:

`apk update; apk add curl`

Comment: Not working if you don't specify "-y" : `apt-get install curl -y`

Comment: @FernandoF That is not a Debian based Linux but Busybox, so this is not just one character difference between `apt` and `apk`.

Comment: apt-get: not found

Comment: While using `FROM node:alpine` I solved this by switching `apt-get`  to `apk` just like [@Fernando F](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1274342/fernando-f) suggested.

Answer (score 71):

Ran into this same issue while using the CURL command inside my Dockerfile. As Gilles pointed out, we have to install curl first. These are the commands to be added in the 'Dockerfile'.

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

# Install prerequisites
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
curl
CMD /bin/bash
```

Comment: Installing `curl` but if you are in control of the command using `curl`, realize that `wget` may be pre-installed in the container already, so if you rewrite the `curl` syntax to use `wget` instead, the result could be a smaller container image.

Comment: This generates an error: `E: List directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial is missing. - Acquire (13: Permission denied)`

Answer (score 52):

So I added curl AFTER my docker container was running.

(This was for debugging the container...I did not need a permanent addition)

I ran my image

```bash
docker run -d -p 8899:8080 my-image:latest
```

(the above makes my "app" available on my machine on port 8899) (not important to this question)

Then I listed and created terminal into the running container.

```bash
docker ps
docker exec -it my-container-id-here /bin/sh
```

If the `exec` command above does not work, check this SOF article:

[Error: Cannot Start Container: stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29535015/error-cannot-start-container-stat-bin-sh-no-such-file-or-directory)

then I ran:

```bash
apk
```

just to prove it existed in the running container, then i ran:

```bash
apk add curl
```

and got the below:

> apk add curl
>
> fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
>
> fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
>
> (1/5) Installing ca-certificates (20171114-r3)
>
> (2/5) Installing nghttp2-libs (1.32.0-r0)
>
> (3/5) Installing libssh2 (1.8.0-r3)
>
> (4/5) Installing libcurl (7.61.1-r1)
>
> (5/5) Installing curl (7.61.1-r1)
>
> Executing busybox-1.28.4-r2.trigger
>
> Executing ca-certificates-20171114-r3.trigger
>
> OK: 18 MiB in 35 packages

then i ran curl:

```bash
/ # curl
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
/ #
```

Note, to get "out" of the drilled-in-terminal-window, I had to open a **new** terminal window and stop the running container:

```bash
docker ps
docker stop my-container-id-here
```

APPEND:

If you don't have "apk" (which depends on which base image you are using), then try to use "another" installer.  From other answers here, you can try:

```
apt-get -qq update

apt-get -qq -y install curl
```

Comment: Thanks for the step by step explanation!

Answer (score 19):

If you are using an **Alpine** based image, you should do

```
RUN
... \
apk add --no-cache curl \
curl ...
...
```

Comment: Why `--no-cache`?

Comment: Hm, understood: we don't want cached package file to be left in our image. Nice touch.

Answer (score 16):

This is happening because there is no package cache in the image, you need to run:

```sh
apt-get -qq update
```

before installing packages, and if your command is in a Dockerfile, you'll then need:

```sh
apt-get -qq -y install curl
```

After that install ZSH and GIT Core:

```sh
apt-get install zsh
apt-get install git-core
```

Getting `zsh` to work in ubuntu is weird since `sh` does not understand the source command. So, you do this to install `zsh`:

```sh
wget https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/raw/master/tools/install.sh -O - | zsh
```

and then you change your shell to zsh:

```sh
chsh -s `which zsh`
```

and then restart:

```sh
sudo shutdown -r 0
```

This problem is explained in depth in this [issue](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/227#issuecomment-825773).

Comment: Installing zsh is not relevant to the solution.

Answer (score 13):

You don't need to install `curl` to download the file into Docker container, use [`ADD` command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add), e.g.

```
ADD https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install /tmp
RUN ruby -e /tmp/install
```

<sup>Note: Add above lines to your `Dockerfile` file.</sup>

---

Another example which installs [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-apt):

```
ADD https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCLIDeb /tmp
RUN bash /tmp/InstallAzureCLIDeb
```

Comment: less time consuming compared to the accepted answer. Just one question though. Does ADD command download the file locally and then adds the file to the image or the download happens within the image?

Comment: @RajaAnbazhagan It's downloaded during `docker build` process of your `Dockerfile` (which runs on your host). Since it's built directly by Docker process, I assume it's downloading the file directly to your image.

Comment: Cool answer, thanks a lot! One more question: should I remove this file later in Dockerfile?

Answer (score 2):

what worked successfully for me was:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.0.4

RUN apt-get update &&\
   apt-get install -y curl
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You could base your image on one that already has `curl`.

A minimalistic one:

```
FROM alpine/curl
```

or a full-fledged one:

```
FROM rockylinux:9
```

Answer (score 0):

To me, the most straightforward solution was just to use `wget` instead of `curl`. `wget` is already installed in the `bash` images.