# Does Kubernetes liveness probes support user authentication with PKIs?

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to access some of our rest endpoints to check that our API container is up and running. If I can specify a PKI I can access our endpoints which currently are all behind authentication. Is this possible?

If not I will have to add a new endpoint.

Comment: when you say PKI you mean you want to use a token to hit a REST endpoint to do a GET request?

Comment: I have a cert in my keychain i get prompted for when accessing out site. I would need to pass this cert in with a request or I get a 403

Comment: does your container have curl in it?

Comment: nope I am using openjdk:8-jdk-alpine but can change it if needed slightly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step 1: add [curl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) to your container image [REF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571711/cant-run-curl-command-inside-my-docker-container), Hint: Modify the Docker file to include curl.

Step 2: (in kubernetes deployment) configure the resource to mount the **certs** needed to query (GET request) the REST endpoint.  [REF](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/) Hint: Follow the way serviceaccount credentials are mounted to a POD.

Step 3: Now use those certs which are mounted to your container. In the [liveness probe](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/#define-a-liveness-command) to curl it the way shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56771903/4451944)

At this point if you have curled successfully with status code 200. you will have a linux comand execution code 0 which lead to successfull liveness check else the pod will be restarted.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to implement it with an external curl script and a liveness probe with [liveness command](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/#define-a-liveness-command), adding certs as secrets and mounting it, and exec curl like:

```
    curl -v --cacert /mounted/cd/secret/ca.pem \
  --key /mounted/secret/key/key.pem --cert /mounted/secret/cert/admin.pem \
  http://liveness/probe/url
```

Regards.