# Problems to access a recent a vue app deployed in docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, vue.js, networking

This is my second **VUE** web application deploy which I can't access. Inside Docker host Linux running `curl localhost:8081`, `curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer`

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:12

WORKDIR /app_teste

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm --version

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8081

CMD ["npm","run","serve"]
```

`dockercompose.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  website:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    container_name: dexter_g_website
```

I was reading here some topics similars which says about binding to 0.0.0.0 would work, however it never happens. Anyone can help/suggest anything?

`docker port dexter_g_webiste`

`8081/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:8081`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [Vue CLI documentation](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/cli-service.html#vue-cli-service-serve), the default port for `serve` command is `8080`.

If you want to serve it to port `8081`, try

```
CMD npm run serve --port 8081
```

---

**Some more debugging tips:**

You can run `curl` command inside the docker container to debug your app.

1. SSH into the running container

```
docker-compose exec -it <container_id> sh
```

2. **[Install CURL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34571766/5599288)**
3. `curl` the URL and see which is working

```
curl http://localhost:8080
curl http://localhost:8081
```

Comment: Jacob, thanks! I was trying to proxy backend, but it's not working