# curl command not found when running inside docker container

Tags: docker, curl, raspberry-pi, debian

Running docker container in Debian on a Raspberry Pi. I have the following code:

```
pi@raspi:~ $ docker container run --rm -it debian
root@64711f73f7da:/# time curl http://google.com
bash: curl: command not found
```

Yet, if I run curl outside of the docker container, it runs fine:

```
pi@raspi:~ $ curl -V
curl 7.64.0 (arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf) libcurl/7.64.0 OpenSSL/1.1.1d zlib/1.2.11 libidn2/2.0.5 libpsl/0.20.2 (+libidn2/2.0.5) libssh2/1.8.0 nghttp2/1.36.0 librtmp/2.3
Release-Date: 2019-02-06
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS IDN IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP HTTP2 UnixSockets HTTPS-proxy PSL
```

I have also tried specifying the path to curl inside the docker container from  `which curl` which specified its location as here: `/usr/bin/curl`. The results were similar to above (`bash: /usr/bin/curl: No such file or directory`)

How can I get curl to run inside of the Docker Container?

Comment: The `debian` base image has a pretty minimal set of software.  It's unusual to use it directly; instead, you'd use it as the base image for a custom image that includes your application.  The Docker [Sample application tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/02_our_app/) might be a good starting point.

Comment: Are you trying to use the curl binary in the host OS? I believe that's unusual, you'd typically install it inside the container.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I just discovered that curl needed to also be inside the container

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't run Curl command inside my Docker Container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571711/cant-run-curl-command-inside-my-docker-container)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer here: [Can't run Curl command inside my Docker Container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571711/cant-run-curl-command-inside-my-docker-container)

But to elaborate: Even though the Debian OS on the Raspberry Pi had curl installed and I could access it from the terminal, the Debian image in the Docker Container also needs curl. So within the Docker Container, both `root@d120d03b37db:/# apt-get update` and `root@d120d03b37db:/# apt-get install curl` needed installed so that the Debian image had reference to curl